# Splitting [jaws] tag - suggestions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

When you browse [jaws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaws) tag on SO, you will see some of the questions are about "Java API for WordNet Searching" (which is in description of the tag) and some concern the [JAWS screen reader](http://www.freedomscientific.com/Products/Blindness/JAWS) so definitely they should be split.

I'd suggest the old tag be renamed to <s>[jaws-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaws-java)</s> (or [jaws-wordnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaws-wordnet)) and the new tag [jaws-screen-reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaws-screen-reader) be created. What do you think? Do you have some better suggestions?

I think the old tag should disappear completely, so that newly tagged questions do not fall under the wrong tag by mistake.

**Edit:** I've created [jaws-screen-reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaws-screen-reader) tag and retagged some of the questions, feel invited to help with the process by browsing [jaws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaws) and retagging. I also wrote wiki entry <s>but it has not yet been verified.</s>

Comment: The search for the tag `screen-readers` yields some easy to spot examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaws+screen-readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the screen reader items were retagged, thanks. I opened [another thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278079/rename-jaws-tag-to-jaws-wordnet) to rename [jaws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaws) to [jaws-wordnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaws-wordnet)

Answer (score 2):

Almost a year after this clean-up was complete, [jaws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaws) was re-created but with a completely different purpose. It was used to refer to the [Serverless-framework](https://github.com/serverless/serverless), then called *Jaws*.

Now that the tag was recreated, you know what would happen. People started to use it for both the Jaws screen reader and the Jaws wordnet.

However, sometime in 2016, the Jaws framework was renamed as serverless, and most of the questions related to the serverless framework was retagged with [serverless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serverless).

As of today, there were 60 questions with the tag. Most of them related to the screen reader, and a the remaining about Jaws wordnet. I now retagged the questions to one of the following tags:

- [jaws-screen-reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaws-screen-reader) x 56 (deleted 4 off topic)
- [jaws-wordnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaws-wordnet) x 4 (deleted 1 off topic)

I then synonymized [jaws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaws) to the screen reader, so that it won't be recreated again, even if someone else comes along and names their product Jaws.