# Rename [jaws] tag to [jaws-wordnet]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Following the [proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277927/splitting-jaws-tag-suggestions) to split, it seems now that all the [jaws-screen-reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaws-screen-reader) questions were retagged properly from [jaws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaws) (thanks to everyone involved).

Could some moderator please rename the remaining [jaws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaws) tag to [jaws-wordnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaws-wordnet)?

Comment: Looks like there's only 19 questions tagged - that's a pretty easy manual retag if you're interested in it. Or are you looking for a tag synonym/blacklist which requires moderator or developer intervention?

Comment: Yep I think the [tag:jaws] tag should be blacklisted if possible, so that people have to choose from [tag:jaws-wordnet] or [tag:jaws-screen-reader]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge complete! (I can’t add a blacklist entry, though, and it’s probably not necessary here.)